# How can I export the attributes of the cells in a selected range

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

**EDIT:** The reason why Excel was crashing was because `getCellProperties()` requires an object with the properties to extract as a parameter. I feel so stupid.

Context: I am building a Addin for Excel using the latest Office Javascript API.

Basically what I want to achieve is to extract and convert to JSON all of the attributes of the selected range. That means, getting borders, fonts, cell values, etc.. I have seen that there are some functions that enable me to get some of the properties for the entire range, however some functions will return null if all the cells in the selected range do not have the same values for a set attribute.

So far, I have thought of using `selectedRange.getCellProperties();` where `selectedRange` is the user's current selection in the worksheet on every cell in the range, but for some reason Excel crashes whenever I try to use this function.
So, the only way I can think of is to extract these attributes manually for each cell in the selected range by using a loop inside a loop. This is of course not optimal for performance and I am confident that there is a better solution possible.

How could I go about doing this?

Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: Did you observe error message when excel crashes? It would be super helpful if you could provide sample code for us to repro this issue.  a script lab gist would be awesome.

Comment: @RaymondLu I don't have time to see the error message when Excel crashes since it closes the window right after. I the only thing I am able to get is the stack trace, which isn't very useful since I don't really understand it. I'll make a quick gist though to show you my program.

Comment: Thanks i got your gist, but it seems it cannot repro in my side, looks like you need a very complex workbook?

Comment: @RaymondLu It's my bad. The gist I sent doesn't have the issue. Previously I was just calling getCellProperties() without any parameters, which wuld lead to Excel crashing. I'm such a fool.

Comment: Your tip is very helpful, now I can repro the crashes with your tips, a bug was logged to track this issue.

Comment: @RaymondLu Glad to know my mistake could contribute to improving Office Js.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this issue. I can repro the crash after removing parameter from getCellProperties. Crashing excel is not right, i have logged an internal bug to track.

Answer (score 0):

From perf consideration, Maybe you could try `getRowProperties` API ? As you can retrieve all properties in a row together. and you can convert row properties into JSON string. The performance could be better.

The document can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#getrowproperties-rowpropertiesloadoptions-

Comment: Although your suggestion might bring some performance improvements, getRowProperties returns null for some properties, if they are not consistant accross the whole row, so that is out of the question for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

(--I'd like to add a comment under Raymond's answer, but i didn't have enough reputation, have to post a new answer :( )

As you already know the crash reason of selectedRange.getCellProperties(), how about making sure the parameter is not null ? getCellProperties is the most convenient way I know for your scenario.

Comment: @MandyMSFT I have used getCellProperties, but there is no need to check for null parameter since I am giving the function an object with static field only so nothing can go wrong here.